# rsync error when copying directories ending in a period

Tags: rsync

This is a weird one since I can't find it mentioned anywhere else, but it's not exactly a niche issue.

I'm trying to copy all of my music over to another server, and the files follow the `[artist]/[artist] - [year] - [album]/[track]. [title]` structure. I'm using the command `rsync -azH /path/to/music user@password:/remote/path/to/music`, and everything copies over fine, except for the songs whose album ends with a period. With these, the directory gets created, but the files do not get copied, giving the error: `rsync: mkstemp "/path/to/music/Dead Kennedys/Dead Kennedys - 1982 - Plastic Surgery DisastersIn God We Trust Inc./.01. Advice From Christmas Past.flac.UVzf3u" failed: No such file or directory (2)`. Note also the `.UVzf3u` on the end of the file - I don't know where that comes from but the actual file is just a `.flac`.

Any ideas?

Comment: What type of server are you copying to, and what is its underlying filesystem type?

Comment: Ensure that `/remote/path/to/music` exists.

Comment: @roaima Ubuntu to Ubuntu, both ext4

Comment: @JimL. it does, it's specifically directories ending in a period that don't work - everything else copies over fine

Comment: It's a known issue on Windows platforms. I've never come across any issues with ext4 -> ext4 though. Very strange indeed.

Comment: @roaima I am ssh'ing into the host machine through Cygwin on Windows. I wouldn't have thought that would come into it at all though?

Comment: So... you `ssh` from Cygwin on Windows to some remote server A. Once logged on there you `rsync` your music files to some other remote server B. Have I got that right? If so, I would agree with you that the Cygwin on Windows part is irrelevant.

Comment: @roaima That's correct

Comment: Perhaps the dot is not really a dot but some unicode char that has "normalization" differences. You might try forcing the C locale at both ends of the rsync. What version of rsync is it at both ends? You can get details of the filenames being sent and received using `--debug=FLIST4`. Use something like `cat -vet` to view the result so any weird characters are seen.

Comment: The `.UVzf3u` is a suffix on the temporary file while being constructed.  When finally approved the file is renamed to its final name.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, this lead me to the answer.  Was trying to rsync from ext4 to fat32 thumb drive on the same Linux system.  Three folders out of a ~hundred, rsync refused to be satisfied with.  Would insist on deleting the destination and copying it again, every time!  Not great for flash drives.

Turned up the verbosity many times, debug flags, info flags, wouldn't tell me why.  Desperate, starting combing thru the source code from github, no clues.  Wasted hours.

Then I noticed the destination folder was missing a period at the end, which led me here.

roaima mentioned it was a "known issue," as if a rsync bug, but that doesn't quite capture it.

Turns out Windows (and by extension Linux' FAT driver) won't allow a filename or folder to end in with a period:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11681207
Sounded vaguely familiar, but I'd forgotten.

So, rsync:

- Doesn't find destination folder "foo."
- Does find destination folder, named "foo"
- Deletes "foo" from destination
- Then copies "foo.", again !
- Resulting in another destination folder, named "foo" !!!
- Rinse and repeat.

No easy fix except changing the source folder name.  Often when this is needed I choose a lookalike character from Unicode.

Comment: rsync is designed to work with Unix file systems.  FAT32 is not a native Unix file system.

Comment: While likely true, not particularly helpful in diagnosing the problem.

Comment: The original poster [told us](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/529297/rsync-error-when-copying-directories-ending-in-a-period#comment979360_529297) they were copying from ext4 to ext4, so although copying to a FAT filesystem will trigger this sort of error, it may not be the issue that the OP had encountered

Comment: @GringoSuave When asking in a Unix group it could very well be.